# Nunjucks - Error: template not found:

Tags: javascript, node.js, nunjucks

The template exists exactly where it's supposed to and the `path.join` is pointed directly to it. Yet still getting a `Error: template not found:`. Also tried using `path.resolve` but gives the same error. Incidentally I'm using exactly the same structure in another file and it works without any problems. Any ideas? Cheers!

```
var deferred = q.defer();
nunjucks.render(path.join(__dirname, 'form.html'), {
          form: extraStuff
        }, function (err, html) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Nunjucks returns error here....');
            return deferred.reject(err);
          }
          console.log('RENDERING....');
          deferred.resolve(html);
        });
```

Comment: So the code that renders the template, and the template file itself, are located in the same directory? What is the file structure of your project?

Comment: form.html is the master html template file that contains nunjucks includes such as  {% include ".tmp/header.html" %}, which are also where they should be. I'm stumped why it's complaining about not finding relevant files when they are there.

Comment: Again though: the .js file that contains the code in your question is in the same directory as the `form.html` file?

Comment: Yes. They're in the same directory. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it complaining about `form.html`, or about the includes?

Comment: The path shown in the `Error: template not found:` ends with `form.html`. I thought it might be the includes but their paths in the form template are correct too as far as I can tell.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, tbh. When you add `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'form.html'))` to the code above, does it yield the correct full path of `form.html`?

Comment: I copied / pasted the path in an empty window by right clicking on the file in the project, then I did `console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'form.html'))`, copied and pasted it directly underneath and the two are identical.

Comment: You do not need to pass the full path to the render function. Pass only name or local path.  `path.join(__dirname)` can be passed to nunjucks configure, but typically `views` (without path) is enough.

Comment: Same error whether I pass `path.join(__dirname, 'form.html')` or `'form.html'`. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have configured nunjucks like below?

```
nunjucks.configure('views')
```

Then nunjucks searches templates relative to this path (views).